# buildozer android debug deploy run not running anything

Tags: android, buildozer

I'm following some tutorial online on pushing kivy files to an android phone. The command:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

finishes successfully without any errors, everything checks out fine. Uploading it to my phone, its no where to be found. Even after adding `run` to the end of the command, my phone just sits idle and nothing happens. Does anyone happen to know where to go to test the app?

Comment: If there are no error messages your app should be installed on your cellphone. Try to uncomment this line `#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D` in the .spec file and run `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat`, if there are some errors in the app that prevent running you'll see them.

Comment: great, that helped. It says that the APK is in the bin directory on my phone, do you happen to know how to access it?

Comment: You need to root your phone for that. But why you want to get there anyway? Do you have any error messages?

Comment: No, I don't have any error messages. I'm trying to run an example kivy program on my phone and from what I've seen some other people have is an actual icon on their home screen for their program that they can tap to run it. When I run the buildozer command, nothing happens and nothing shows up in the kivy launcher or on my home screen. It says ```# Android packaging done!
# APK yoinkpackage__armeabi-v7a-1.0-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk available in the bin directory```, so I was thinking if I could access the bin directory I could move it somewhere where I could actually use the program.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about that, `bin` is in buildozer folder, apk is there

Comment: Sorry, I mean where is it on my cell phone?

Comment: That message you've sent means that apk is ready and it's in `bin` folder of buildozer. After that message buildozer should install it on your phone and run. I really don't know why it doesn't do that, but you can install it manually.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. adb installed it on my phone. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`buildozer android debug deploy run` actually works as intended on my `Kivy 2.0.0/buildozer 1.2.0` install, while `buildozer android debug logcat deploy run` just runs logcat without deploying or running anything.

Anyway, this ["alternative" approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59403967/1396334) to the problem works as well if you don't want to rely completely on `buildozer`.